# JavaScript - по клику на кнопку сохранить картинку из src

Tags: javascript, html5, изображения

Есть `img src="/index.php?img=12345&timestamp=1234567890"`, в котором timestamp постоянно меняется (идёт стрим с камеры или дисплея, кадры в jpeg). Нужно по клику на кнопку открыть диалог сохранения jpeg файла из текущего кадра - то есть, проще говоря, "сфоткать" и сохранить.

**Это можно сделать на клиенте средствами HTML5/JS без участия сервера?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Конечно можно

```
var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.setAttribute("href", youUrl);
    link.setAttribute("download", "image.jpg");

    link.click();
```

Comment: Спасибо! Не знал про download ))

Answer (score 5):

Используйте ссылку с аттрибутом [`download`](http://htmlbook.ru/html/a/download)

```
<a href="/path/to/image.jpg" download>
  <img src="/path/to/image.jpg">
</a>
```

Ссылка на рабочий пример https://codepen.io/lukas-pierce/pen/egwydY

Comment: Сейчас этот пример не работает. Просто загружается новая вкладка с оригиналом изображения